# What percent of samples have a specific gene?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking to calculate how many samples have a specific gene.  My dataframe is posted below as a dput().  I want to be able to say "*mmoX* is in 43.5% of samples" and I have tried:

```
library(tidyverse)
example %>%
  group_by(Sample,gene) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(average = mean(value)) %>%
  dplyr::reframe(average / sum(average)) -> gene.perc
```

Where I am expecting `gene.perc` to contain two columns: one of the gene ID and the other of the percent abundance. I think I have the percent abundance in this output, but I am missing the gene labels!

In the provided example, I am expecting to see *fwdF* is present in two out of eleven samples, so that row would be `fwdF | 0.18`, compared to AMACR which is present in 1 out of eleven samples so that row would be `AMACR | 0.09`.

But I'm going a little insane because I feel this should be super simple and any help is appreciated.

```
> dput(example)
structure(list(gene = c("fwdF", "AMACR", "mtrA", "mrtC", "mtrD", 
"pmoA", "pmoC", "pmoB", "mtrF", "mmoX", "fwdF"), value = c(79L, 
337L, 34L, 108L, 35L, 27L, 207L, 89L, 0L, 15L, 354L), Sample = c("LIL19-M", 
"LIL19-M", "LIL19-M", "LIL19-M", "LIL19-M", "SCS18-4", "SCS18-4", 
"SCS18-4", "SCS18-4", "SCS18-4", "SCS18-5"), Pond = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("RHM", "TS", 
"SCS", "LIL", "STN", "STS"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 641L, 642L, 643L, 644L, 646L, 649L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `example |> count(gene) %>% mutate(share = n / sum(n))`?

Comment: What does the `value` column have to do with your calculation of prevalence among the observations?

Comment: Nothing for this calculation.  That was just a carryover from my real df into the example.

Comment: The above code provides this error when used on the example dataset: `Error in count(., gene) : Argument 'x' is not a vector: list`

Comment: The code in Jon's comment works for me using the example data provided. If you're getting an error, the data must be different to that in the example.

Comment: Okay, thank you all!!

Answer (score 1):

You may try this if I caught your idea:

```
example %>%
  mutate(nsmpl = unique(Sample) %>% length()) %>%
  group_by(gene, nsmpl) %>%
  summarise(sperc = n() ) %>%
  transmute(gene, sperc = sperc / nsmpl * 100)
```